# How do you make a function that only takes strings, take variables in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to run a function in Powershell called Get-OSArchitecture which tells me whether a computer has a 32bit or 64bit system when you give it a domain name. However, it only accepts strings such as "SALES-DENNY" and not variables with stored strings such as $string1. I've played around with something called Out-String but this function is really stubborn with getting strings and nothing to do with variables.

The following code is for getting the global Get-OSArchitecture function:

```
function global:Get-OSArchitecture { 

#Requires -Version 2.0 
[CmdletBinding()] 
 Param  
   ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
               Position=1, 
               ValueFromPipeline=$true, 
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
    [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME       
   )#End Param  

Begin 
{ 
 Write-Verbose "Retrieving Computer Info . . ." 
} 
Process 
{ 
$ComputerName | foreach {  
$ErrorActionPreference = 0 
$Computer = $_ 
$Windir,$OSArchitecture,$OSVersion = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ |  
    foreach {$_.WindowsDirectory,$_.OSArchitecture,$_.Version} 
$SysDrive = ($Windir -split ":")[0] + "$" 
# $OSVersion[0] 
# $OSArchitecture is only suppored on OSVersion -ge 6 
# I was going to test for that, however now I just test if $OSArchitecture -eq $True 
Write-Verbose "Operating System version on $Computer is: $OSVersion" 
if ($OSArchitecture) 
    { 
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{  
        Hostname=$Computer 
        OSArchitecture=$OSArchitecture 
        SysDrive=$SysDrive 
        OSVersion=$OSVersion 
        WinDir=$WinDir 
        } 
    } 
else 
    { 
        # check the program files directory 
        write-verbose "System Drive on $Computer is: $SysDrive" 
        $x64 =  "\\$Computer\" + $SysDrive + "\Program Files (x86)" 
        if (test-path ("\\$Computer\" + $SysDrive)) 
            { 
                if (test-path $x64) 
                    { 
                        New-Object PSObject -Property @{  
                        Hostname=$Computer 
                        OSArchitecture="64-bit" 
                        SysDrive=$SysDrive 
                        OSVersion=$OSVersion 
                        WinDir=$WinDir 
                        } 
                    } 
                elseif (!(test-path $x64)) 
                    { 
                        New-Object PSObject -Property @{  
                        Hostname=$Computer 
                        OSArchitecture="32-bit" 
                        SysDrive=$SysDrive 
                        OSVersion=$OSVersion 
                        WinDir=$WinDir 
                        } 
                    } 
            } 
        else {"Something wrong determining the System Drive"}  
    } 
} | select Hostname,OSArchitecture,SysDrive,WinDir,OSVersion 

}#Process             
End             
{    

}#End  


}#Get-OSArchitecture
```

My problem begins below.

```
$string1 = "SALES-DENNY"

Get-OSArchitecture $string1
```

The above fails.
The below works.

```
Get-OSArchitecture "SALES-DENNY"
```

I expect the function to give out the correct architecture of the computer with the name "SALES-DENNY" but if I don't put it in as a string I always get a blank result.

Comment: There should be no difference between passing a string literal and a variable containing a string. There is not enough information in your question to diagnose the  problem. Please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you say it fails, how does it fail? What error do you get? Also, please make sure you make the code sample just small enough that it still works to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Odd, it worked for me.  I saved the code above in get-osarchitecture.ps1, then entered `. .\get-osarchitecture` to define the function, then it worked.

Comment: No response anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Although it should not matter if you give the computername as hardcoded string or as a name or IP in a variable, I do believe you could improve the function by not testing the `Program Files (x86)` directory.
Instead, there are two other WMI functions you can rely on to get the 'bitness' of the OS:

```
function Get-OSArchitecture {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
    process {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
            Write-Verbose "Retrieving info for computer '$computer'"

            $info = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer | 
                    Select-Object @{Name = 'HostName'; Expression = { $_.PSComputerName}},
                                  OSArchitecture,
                                  @{Name = 'SysDrive'; Expression = { '{0}$' -f ($_.SystemDrive).Substring(0,1) }},
                                  @{Name = 'WinDir'; Expression = { $_.WindowsDirectory}},
                                  @{Name = 'OSVersion'; Expression = { $_.Version }}

            if ($info.OSArchitecture) {
                $info.OSArchitecture = '{0}-bit' -f ($info.OSArchitecture -replace '\D+','')
            }
            else {
                $info.OSArchitecture = '{0}-bit' -f (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $computer).AddressWidth
                # or do:
                # $info.OSArchitecture = '{0}-bit' -f (((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer).SystemType -replace '\D+', '') -replace '86', '32')
            }
            # emit info
            $info
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps